# Problem uninstalling and installing Java on new pc running Windows 7 64 bit os

Tags: java

I have a new Dell Studio XPS running Windows 7 64 bit os.  I am attending online classes which require IE 8 and Java version 6 build 20.  The pc came with IE 8 32 bit and Java 6 build 21 already installed.  I tried to uninstall Java using add and remove programs but after about 45 minutes of "Preparing to remove application" I got an error refering to a missing dll file and the uninstall failed.  I used a third party program to remove Java and downloaded Java 6 build 20.

My problem is when I try to install it I get the box telling me "Installing program ... this may take a few minutes" however after 30 to 45 minutes nothing has happend and there is no indication in the progress bar that anything is happening then all of a sudden the program bar is full and the program is supposedly installed.  When I try to run it however it doesn't work.  Someone help please! I can't get access to my classwork with out this!

Thanks

Comment: Which missing dll file?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/download-freeware-version.php) to uninstall Java.

Some more advice : Disable any anti-spyware or anti-virus software on your system during the installation. Always execute installations using "Run as Administrator" or disable UAC during the installation.

See the following links:

[Error 1721: There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1721.xml)
[Why is Java not found on x64 Windows Vista after installation?](http://geeks.pirillo.com/profiles/blogs/why-is-java-not-found-on-x64)